# Determine wether X and Y are independent with unknown joint PDF and/or marginal PDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

This is the standard formula to determine if random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Sometimes $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ or $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ are unknown and can be quite a hassle to calculate. I have compiled few shortcuts I have been using to determine relation between $X$ and $Y$. Any proof to verify or fringe cases to falsify my hypothesis are greatly appreciated.

**Scenario 1:**

$X$ is restricted by $Y$. Example: $0\le X\le Y$

$X$ and $Y$ are restricted by eachother. Example: $0\le X^2\le Y, \quad 0\le Y^2\le X$

The two scenarios above always imply that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

**Scenario 2:**

$\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)$  contain variable $Y$ and/or $\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)$  contain variable $X$

Does this imply that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

**Scenario 1+2:**

If all the conditions above are satisfied, does it imply that $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Senario 2 should never happen.  $f_X(x)$ should always be a function only of $x$ (well, and constants and parameters).

Comment: But if you meant  the *conditional* $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$, then the presence of $y$ in the expression it clearly indicates a dependency.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the support for the joint distribution indicates a clear dependency --such as you say, if they restrict each other-- then indeed how can the random variables be considered independent?   However, a **lack** of such restriction does **not** signify independence.
2. If the *conditional* measure is non-constant with respect to the conditioning variable (ie: does not equal the marginal measure), then that is a clear indication for dependence.   Ie: independence occurs *exactly when* $\forall y:f_X(x)=f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ when $f_{X}, f_{X\mid Y}$ are the marginal and conditional probability density (or mass) functions .